# MS Excel > concat vertical cells within irregular range

Tags: excel, excel-2010

[image]

I am not sure I can ask about just excel problems on stackoverflow.com.
Just let me know gently If I am making mistakes.

I need to concat vertical cells in col3.
Their ranges depend on column 'num' which has numbers like 1(A2), 2(A7), 3(A9).
So the result would be like 'aaa,bbb,ddd,eee', then 'ff', 'gg,abc'.
I tried to use CONCATENATE or TEXTJOIN but I realized it wasn't that simple to do it.

Is there any way to do it?
Or do I need to learn VBA?
Hope someone knows can guide to do it...

Comment: To me it is not clear how the value of num effects your desired output

Comment: From where you are getting `aaa,bbb,ddd,eee`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Column E is a helper column, you can then add an extra column  (F) to get only required results.

Given the information supplied, you can do this with formula:

**Helper Column**

Cell E2 - leave blank

Cell E3 `=IF(A3="",D2&CHAR(44)&D3,D3)`

Cell E4 `=IF(A4="",IF(D4="",E3,IF(AND(A3<>"",D3=""),D4,E3&CHAR(44)&D4)),IF(D4="","",D4))`

**Results Column**

Cell F2 `=IF(A3<>"",D2,"")`

Cell F3 `=IF(A4="",IF(E4="",E3&",",""),E3)`

Autofill E4 and F3 to the end of the data range by clicking on the small square on bottom right of the cells and dragging down.

It does not matter what is in Column A, but where there is data in a cell then it will start a new text join chain.

Comment: This solved my problem without using the functions in the lastest version of Excel. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula - sorry no explanation until later when I will tidy it up:

```
=LET(freq,DROP(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A15="",ROW(A2:A15)),IF(A2:A15<>"",ROW(A2:A15))),1)+1,cols,MAX(freq),rows,ROWS(freq),
array,SEQUENCE(rows,cols,0),start,XMATCH(QUOTIENT(array,cols)+1,A2:A15),strings,IF(MOD(array,cols)+1>freq,"",IF(INDEX(D2:D15,start+MOD(array,cols))="","",INDEX(D2:D15,start+MOD(array,cols)))),
BYROW(strings,LAMBDA(s,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,s))))
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution looks exactly what I want. However, I copied it and it gives me '#NAME?' error.

Comment: Oh.. and I realized that is because my Excel version is 2010, there is no function named textjoin or probably other functions too.

Comment: Oh well it was fun finding a solution. Hopefully one of the answers using helper columns will work for you - meanwhile plz edit the tags in your question to specify Excel 2010.

Comment: Did any of the other solutions work?

Comment: @TomSharpe Thank you for editing and also your answer even thought I couldn't use it but it looks perfect for me. haha

Answer (score 0):

The values in the **num** column don't appear to affect the sorting.
The **TEXTJOIN** should work in this instance.
Setting the *ignore_empty* to **TRUE** will skip the empty cells.

**Formula:**

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,D2:D11)
```

**Results:**

```
aaa,bbb,ddd,eee,ff,gg,abc
```

If you need a vertical list then use the **FILTER** function.

**Formula:**

```
=FILTER(D2:D11,D2:D11<>"")
```

**Result:**

```
aaa
bbb
ddd
eee
ff
gg
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare new column in `E` with following formula (starting from `E2`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),E1,A2)
```

And from there you'd have to add column `F` with following formula (starting from `F2`:

```
=IF(E2<>E1,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,D2),TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,D2,F1))
```

Which would result in this:
[image]